# Prevent DateTimePicker2 to go under the date set by DateTimePicker1

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

I have two dateTimePicker named dtpFromDate and dtpToDate which has a "date range" function. How can I make the value of dtpToDate does not go under the value of dtpFromDate? Right now, my dtpToDate can go under the value of dtpFromDate.

Comment: wpf? winforms? asp.net?

Comment: sorry i'd forgot.. it's windows form..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming its Winforms there are a couple of ways to do it, ASP.net would be similar.

You would need to add handlers to Value Changed, either on the To Date picker, or the From depending on which way you want to do it (or both)

```
    private void dtpFromDate_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Set the min date of the to date when the from date is changed
        dtpToDate.MinDate = dtpFromDate.Value;
    }

    private void dtpToDate_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //set the to date to the date selected, or the 'from' date if the 'to' date is lower
        //(if this) ? (then this) : (otherwise this)
        dtpToDate.Value = dtpToDate.Value < dtpFromDate.Value ? dtpFromDate.Value : dtpToDate.Value;
    }
```